# Change the width of spines in colobar axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to change the width of spines for both axis:

```
img = np.random.normal(size=(100, 100))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cax = ax.imshow(img)

cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=np.linspace(0, 70, 8))
[i.set_linewidth(3) for i in cbar.ax.spines.itervalues()]
[i.set_linewidth(3) for i in ax.spines.itervalues()]
```

However, as the result I get the following:

[image]

How can I change the length of the spines for the colorer axis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would have expected your solution to work but a possible work around is to set `axes.linewidth` and remove the `set_linewidth(3)` lines

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 3
```

I figured out this work around by finding this:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/ac8f340c9a771871c894aecdc12a9111958271dd/lib/matplotlib/colorbar.py#L429

*edit*

Alternatively you can set the outline line width directly:

```
img = np.random.normal(size=(100, 100))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cax = ax.imshow(img)

cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=np.linspace(0, 70, 8))
cbar.outline.set_linewidth(3)
[i.set_linewidth(3) for i in ax.spines.itervalues()]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! I tried to use `cbar.outline`, but it can't find the attribute. For what version of matplotlib do you provide the solution? I am plotting it using a legacy code that uses the version 1.5.1 and can't update it... and I would prefer to use a local solution that do not involve changing global `rcParams` as there are many plots that are visualised.

Comment: Hm, I just tried with matplotlib v1.5.1 and python2.7 and it seemed to work. Are you sure that's the exact version you are using? I was also using the TkAgg backend instead of the deault qt one if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3):

You may try to set the frame of the colorbar axes on again, such that the changes to its spines can take an effect.

```
cbar.ax.set_frame_on(True)
```

Complete example (only tested with matplotlib 2.0)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = np.random.normal(size=(100, 100))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(img)

cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ticks=np.linspace(0, 70, 8))
cbar.ax.set_frame_on(True)
[i.set_linewidth(3) for i in cbar.ax.spines.itervalues()]
[i.set_linewidth(3) for i in ax.spines.itervalues()]

plt.show()
```

[image]